# Prove $\bigcup_{p \in P}C_p = (\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i) \times (\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I would like to prove following:

> Suppose $\{A_i \mid i \in I\}$ and $\{B_i \mid i \in I\}$ are indexed
>   families of sets.
>
> For each $(i,j) \in I \times I$ let $C_{i,j} = A_i \times B_j$, and
>   let $P = I \times I $ Prove that $$\bigcup_{p \in P}C_p = (\bigcup_{i
>  \in I} A_i) \times (\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i)$$

My attempt:

$(\rightarrow)$

Let $w = (x,y)$ be arbitrary element such that $w\in \bigcup_{p \in P}C_p$. Then it implies that there is some index $z \in P$, such that $w \in C_z$. Let $z = (k,l)$, where $k,l \in I$. Then we have $w \in C_{k,l}$ which can be rewritten as $w \in A_{k} \times B_{l}$, which implies that $x \in A_{k}$ and $y \in B_l$. Since $k \in I$, we have $A_k \subseteq A$.  And because all elements of all subsets in $A$ are in $(\bigcup_{i
 \in I} A_i)$, we can conclude that $x \in (\bigcup_{i
 \in I} A_i)$.

By the same reasoning: since $l \in I$, we have $B_l \subseteq B$, and because all elements of all subsets in $B$ are in $(\bigcup_{i
 \in I} B_i)$, we can conclude that $y \in (\bigcup_{i
 \in I} B_i)$.

Therefore, $w \in (\bigcup_{i
 \in I} A_i) \times (\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i)$

Since $w$ was an arbitrary element, we conclude that

$$\bigcup_{p \in P}C_p \subseteq (\bigcup_{i
 \in I} A_i) \times (\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i)$$

$(\leftarrow)$

Let $w = (x,y)$ be arbitrary element such that $w\in (\bigcup_{i
 \in I} A_i) \times (\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i)$. It implies that $x$ is in some subset of $A$, call it $A_k$ ($k \in I$), and $y$ is in some subset of $B$, call it $B_{l}$ ($l \in I$). Then we can rewrite $A_{k} \times B_{l}$ as  $C_{k,l}$. Since $k \in I$, and $l \in I$, we have $(k,l) \in P$, and thus we conclude that $C_{(k,l)} \subseteq \bigcup_{p \in P}C_p$, which means that $w \in \bigcup_{p \in P}C_p$. Arbitrary element was considered, hence

$$(\bigcup_{i
 \in I} A_i) \times (\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i) \subseteq \bigcup_{p \in P}C_p$$.

We've shown both directions, thus we have our result

$$\bigcup_{p \in P}C_p = (\bigcup_{i
 \in I} A_i) \times (\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i)$$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your fine proof is correct !